# How to send message from zabbix to telegram?

Tags: bash, notifications, zabbix, telegram

I have problems with notifications on zabbix to telegram messenger.
So, I specified different guides for that. But not successful.

For example I use this  [guides](http://tobias.ws/blog/zabbix-com-notificacoes-pelo-telegram/)

This solutions works for bash. But I can send this from zabbix.

```
export to=$1;
export subject=$2;
export body=$3;


tgpath=/usr/src/tg/zabbix
cd ${tgpath}
(sleep 5; echo "msg $to $subject $body"; echo "safe_quit") | 
${tgpath}/telegram-cli -k /etc/telegram-cli/mykey.pub -W
```

Key `telegram-cli -e` does not work correctly with a login name and with format `user#XXXXXX;`

I dont want to use some  API to send message.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: We use Jaconda.im to send notification from zabbix to telegram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is not equal to the blog post.

The steps are:

0 - Compile

```
cd /usr/src
git clone --recursive https://github.com/vysheng/tg.git
cd tg
./configure
make
mkdir viacron
cp bin/telegram-cli viacron/
cp tg-server.pub viacron/
cd viacron
```

1 - Create a file `/usr/src/tg/viacron/telegram.config` an put this:

```
default_profile = "viacron";  
viacron = {  
config_directory = "/usr/src/tg/viacron/";  
};
```

2 - Create a file `/usr/src/tg/viacron/telegram.config` an put this:

```
#!/bin/bash
MAIN_DIRECTORY="/usr/src/tg/viacron/"
USER=$1
SUBJECT=$2
TEXT=$3
cd $MAIN_DIRECTORY
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo "Error to enter in the main directory"
        exit 1
fi
./telegram-cli -k tg-server.pub -c telegram.config -WR -e "msg $USER $SUBJECT" || exit 1
exit 0
```

3 - Change permissions:

```
chmod +x /usr/src/tg/viacron/telegram_standalone.sh
chown -R yourUser: /usr/src/tg/
```

4 - Test:

```
/usr/src/tg/viacron/telegram_standalone.sh user#12345 "GNU is not unix"
```

5 - Put `AlertScriptsPath=/usr/src/tg/viacron/` in `zabbix_server.conf` and restart the server

6 - In zabbix, add new media type with name `telegram_standalone.sh`

More information in https://gist.github.com/gnumoksha/a95f237d82733ce1f748 and http://tobias.ws/blog/zabbix-com-notificacoes-pelo-telegram/

Comment: The answer has changed months ago.

Answer (score 0):

Now Telegram supported by default
check:

https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/telegram

and there is extra settings check:

https://youtu.be/TpP6NpS9jjg?t=143